# Laravel 5 - Post JSON data using curl

Tags: php, laravel, post, curl

I'm trying to POST data using command line using curl.

```
curl -v POST -d ' { "data1": "sample1", "data2": "sample2" } ' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: BASIC vkslnkg561mZEqCq3l3RglAOAZ7d8XBeg2VjIAyC" http://localhost/Bowling/public/api/foo
```

When I try to POST from POSTMAN, I get the data back. But when I use curl, I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

My routes.php

```
Route::any('api/foo', function () { 
    return json_encode("Some Data"); 
});
```

May I know is it something wrong with my curl statement or some authentication problem that I need to fix in Laravel.

I even tried with

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key":"val"}' -H "Authorization: BASIC 0xD8BC2CLksEMh1ScRdG8dWanCDazYiQsGL7sYnl" http://localhost/Bowling/public/api/foo
```

Comment: Have you looked at your logs to see why you are getting a 500 error?

Comment: Hey james, it says local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in G:\wamp\www\Bowling\vendor\compiled.php:2440

But I get the output with same token for 

    curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: BASIC 0xD8BC2CLksEMh1ScRdG8dWanCDazYiQsGL7sYnl" http://localhost/Bowling/public/api/leagues

Comment: If I remove 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken', in app/Http/Kernel.php, then it works. But I need the authentication token to be passed.

Comment: How will you ensure that the token you are passing for the CSRF token is always correct as it will generate one for each session?

Comment: It changes every time, but this is a kind of task which is assigned to me where I got to authenticate using the CSRF token. I was thinking of a solution to read the CSRF token from what is sent in header and verify.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in what you are doing. Its just the delay in your calls which is causing the token mismatch. I faced the same issue while manually testing my APIs via postman. Sad that Laravel doesn't have any  decorator to exempt CSRF like Django.

On Postman, I was able to test my APIs issues by writing a route that returns a `csrf token`. I then copy that token and pass it as form-data in my next `POST` call. I couldn't find any other alternative.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hey @Vishal, that's a good way of approach, the problem is the data and the csrf token has to be sent in single attempt. I'm able to get the expected results using Postman.

Comment: have you tried sending the csrf token with `_token` as key and csrf_token as value along with the post data. 

however to get CSRF token, you need to at least make a GET call to the server. So posting data and getting csrf cant be done in a go.

Comment: The csrf token is given to us, i=so basically we have a current csrf token with us. Just need to send in header with the data. In postman I used key as _token and the csrf value. But when I send using curl, its throwing 500 Server error.

Comment: If you already have a csrf and then you make a new call then, It will 110% throw HTTP 500. Not clear with what you want to achieve